# Google maps on altervista

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to implement Google Maps on altervista?
I need to write some php code which takes GPS coordinates from evry row of a DB MySQL and then set a marker on the maps.
Can i do these on altervista or on any other free domain?
Thank your for your answers and sorry for my english

Comment: yes is possible  ..

Comment: SO is not a coding for hire site. Either find a turnkey solution or try to do it yourself. Come back when you have a specific question about the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes is possible because the use of  google library is performed  on the client  browser .. so the server side php just access to db for data and render  the values you need (coord)  to the client for the javascript related execution for show the marker ..

this is normal behavior for google maps architecture  .. and is indipendent for the fact the server is free or not  .. once is (obvious) accessible by internet .

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea how to  "render the values you need to the client for the...",can you suggest me something,please??

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with your application. Can return the values directly to the html page or respond with echo to a json request .. It seems that the problem is not tied to hosting on altervista .. i seem to be tied to what you know ..

Comment: Yes..I am pretty newbie in these arguments..This post was just to check the feasibility of my idea.
Anyway I'd prefer the first one( Thank for your time)